# HP Envy 15 wifi toggle

Tags: hp, function-keys

I just got Ubuntu 13.10 on my new HP laptop. The <kbd>F6</kbd> key is for mute and when you use it the orange light lights up on the key and the sound turns off. <kbd>F12</kbd> is for wifi (on windows 8 it toggles airplane mode) if I press it, it does nothing. Is there something I can do to have the button turn WIFI off and the light work?

Comment: If you run `xev | grep key` and press the button, do you get any output?

Comment: nope, nothing, other function keys do though